# ASP.NET Core how to change policy requirements based on user selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

In my Blazor webassembly project I can see all roles, delete and add new ones. I can also assign a role to a user and authenticate the user based on that.

Now I have for example my `RolesController.cs`:

```cs
// GET: api/Persons
[Authorize(Policy = "SeeAllRoles")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<IdentityRole>>> GetRoles()
{
     return await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
}

// GET api/<RolesController>/5
[Authorize(Policy = "GetRole")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IdentityRole>> GetRole(string id)
{
    var role = await _roleManager.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
    if (role == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return role;
}
```

Every controller has a unique policy for each action. So that I can restrict each action individually. Normally I would just define the policy in `Startup.cs`, add `.RequireRole("Admin")` or something to it and now every user in this role would have access to the policy I specified.

To the question: I want to have a list of roles, as I have now, with the ability to select which policy should be included in this role. So that I can login to my application go to `Roles` and add a new role `NewsDisplay` and only select policies necessary to view the news feed. Then I can add users for my various displays and put all of them in the newly created `NewsDisplay` role.

I guess this is possible but can´t find a sufficient solution to this. Would be nice if someone could give me examples, links, ideas.

Comment: You using ASP.NET Core Identity? It has everything you need. Rules as an entity and claims. A role is basically a bag of claims, same as a user can be a bag of claims. So you create a role named "Admin" and add claims to it which define admin, for the claims you have policies in your startup. Should be well documented already. The claims will be automatically added to the users IdentityClaims if he has a specific role. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I want to add policies to roles so that I don´t need to give each user 100 policies instead add the 100 policies to a role and give each user just that role.

Maybe that is possible with the claims you mentioned but currently I am not that familiar with claims so would be helpful if you could give me some examples other than the general Microsoft one.

Comment: Wait, roles also have claims. So you mean I can add my role, then when I select a policy in my UI wich this role should have I add the claim for the policy to the role, then in my startup.cs I check for that claim?

Comment: Yea, roles are "bags of claims" too, i.e. you could have a claim `roles` and `roles.manage`. The `roles.manage` could be added to the role named "admin" or "manager" where as the `roles` claim (read roles) could be added to the user role. When the user belongs to both "user" and "admin" role, both claims will be added to his property bag.

Comment: @Tseng thanks, tested it by adding claims to roles manually in the database and it worked. Do you know how I avoid claims being applied twice? Like when in your example `roles` are added to "admin" and `roles.manage` are added to "manager" now one user is in both roles "admin" and "manager", this user would have the claim `roles` two times.